# Django IntegrityError with CreateView

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a feature to a website to add new song information. The problem arises after the user fills out a song_form.html and tries to submit the new song and it returns an IntegrityError. It says NOT NULL constraint failed: music_song.album_id. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
#models.py
class Album(models.Model):
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    album_cover = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Song(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title

#views.py
class CreateSong(generic.CreateView):
    model = Song
    fields = ['song_title', 'file_type']
```

Comment: `album` is a required field on your model, but you have excluded it from the fields in your `CreateSong` form, hence the error.

Comment: Why does this surprise you? You specify that a song needs an album, but your CreateSong only has fields for song_title and file_type.

Comment: I don't want the album field to be filled in by the user. The album field needs to be automatically defined as the album.id but I am unsure of how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean for the album to be required? If so, you'll need to add it as a field to your Song form, but if not you'll need to declare your foreign key constraint as nullable like so:

```
album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

(remembering to make migrations for the app, then migrate after the change)

Comment: Thank you. Setting null=True does solve the IntegrityError problem and makes it so the field is not required.

Comment: Glad to hear it. If you feel that's what you were looking for, you can mark it as the answer for future reference to the question.